# Excel VBA - checking for combined duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I'm regularly getting datasets compiled in various worksheets that need to be added to an ever extending master table (i. e. new month, new data). However, before basically copying the dataset from the source into the master table, it needs to be checked for combined duplicates. Each line of data is amongst others specified by a date (MM-YYYY) and its unique identifier (a number). For any unique identifier there can't be another line of data for the same period, even if for whatever reason the other information of the line should differ.

For example, the master table contains the following two lines of data:

```
12-2019 12345 Dog
12-2019 59235 Cat
```

A new dataset has the line *12-2019 12345 Bird* in it but it shouldn't be copied to the master table as a line of data for *12345* with the period *12-2019* already exists. Does anyone have a solution?

If it would only be one value to check, I would have went with some equivalents to lookup or index and match, but since this is about combined duplicates, I'm a little lost.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. you've told us what you want to accomplish, but not what you have tried nor what the exact problem is

Comment: For each new row, use `Filter` to return the set of rows from Master Data where date and Id match.  It should return 0 or 1 rows. If 0, add the new row

Comment: a logic: for each cell in source column id, find in master table column id, if true get the offset cell value of source column id to the left which is the mm-yyyy then compare to the offset cell value of master column id to the left which is also the mm-yyyy, if not equal then copy the row values from the source  to the master table

Comment: also  for each cell in source column id, find in master table column id, if not found then you can directly copy the row values from the source to the master table

Comment: I actually solved it like @chrisneilsen suggested with two filters and counting the rows based on visible cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved it like @chrisneilsen suggested with two filters and counting the rows based on visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and if you don't mind to use a helper column ...

Original data is something like this: 
[image]

After a code to copy new data from source and paste it under the original data, the sheet look something like this:

[image]

Please ignore the yellow color as it's used just to show that yellow row need to be deleted because A - 123, A - 456, C - 124 are duplicate.

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim col As Integer

col = 1000 'helper column, column 1000

With Sheets("Sheet4") 'change if needed
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)) 'change if needed
End With

With rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count, col)
    .Columns(col).Value = "=concatenate(" & rg(1, 1).Address(0, 0) & "," & rg(1, 2).Address(0, 0) & ")"
    .Columns(col).Value = .Columns(col).Value
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=col, Header:=xlNo
    .Columns(col).Clear
End With

End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

The process, instead of checking each cell in the source and if meet criteria then do copy paste to the target sheet - you just copy the whole source into the target sheet then fill the helper column with concatenate formula , then remove duplicate based on the concatenate value and retain the first occurance.

Please note, the code assumes that after the last column of the data table, the rest of the columns are free.

Answer (score 0):

You can find duplicates, using a helper column as in this example:

[image]

The formula is (when cell D1 is activated):

```
=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$3,A1,B$1:B$3,B1)
```

You can use it as a way to filter duplicates, as an entry for conditional formatting, ...